# Xcode 8 Build with Jenkins CI

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, swift2, xcode8

I'm having issues with automated jenkins build on a mac pro using Xcode 8.1 with xcodebuild.

I would like my setup to:

1. Pull down code for git (working)
2. Archive (Archive fails)
3. Create .ipa
4. Deploy to TestFairy

My archive script is failing but still creating ProjectName-Daily.xcarchive file:

`xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName-Daily -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath ~/ProjectName-Daily.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=1234567890`

Fails with the following on the terminal with no description on error. I also tried `-verbose` and no luck

[image]

I then tried to build it manually and get a build succeeds with the following errors:

[image]

I then went to archive the build on Xcode and it worked just fine. Not sure why the script isn't working on the CI machine. Also tried the script on my personal macbook pro and it worked just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is clearly stating that your script failed to getting invoked. Have you set the proper execution right to your script?

Do the following,

1. Change to the directory your script resides.
2. grant the script execution right as chmod +x YOUR_SCRIPT.sh

Comment: Archive still failed after swapping to directory and trying the script again.

Comment: can you post how you have specified the script?

Comment: xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName-Daily -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath ~/ProjectName-Daily.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=1234567890

Comment: it appears as if your path to xcworkspace is not correctly specified as it has troubled finding it

Comment: The build succeeds and runs for about 5 minutes. It creates the archive file and fails at the end with no error description. :(

Comment: Well can't help without any hint or error.

Comment: Got a bit closer to narrowing down the problem. Seems to fail through the jenkins job of just pulling down the source code and running the script. When I clone the project down on the machine and run the script it works fine.  Can it be a permission issue? Kind of weird that it looks like the script is running the archive just fine with successful builds and just fails at the end.

Comment: Try setting you archive path to somewhere in the local directory, e.g. ./ProjectName-Daily.xcarchive - it's possible Jenkins is having trouble writing to the home folder (which is likely JENKINS_HOME)